# webpage to PDF conversion on android

Tags: android, pdf

i am looking for some libraries for converting webpages to pdf on android and have not found any good articles or sources. basically i want to develop a native app that opens up webpages and converts them to pdf on user choice.

Comment: Can you not create a web service? Have an activity that the user inputs a URL, then make a web request to a server that processes the web page to a PDF (which will be quicker than the Android device doing it) and then return a link to downloading the pdf and displaying it?

Comment: I guess you can look into Mozilla mobile browser source code, it can do this

Comment: hi, well what im looking for is a solution that lets me create pdf files on the device. i found dolphin hd browser with a plugin that does the job but still i want to make my own app for creating pdf against a webpage it would be great. thanks

Comment: thanks nandeesh i checked mozilla browser and the problem with it is it does not support all devices :)